# Listview luggy only on Samsung Galaxy Note 10'' 2014

Tags: android, android-listview

it can seem stupid, but I have an app with various ListView. The row layouts are very simple (just some TextView), the Viewholder pattern is implemented and the dataset is really small (about 100 rows). The lists are very smooth on all devices except for the galasy note 10'': on this device the lists are DRAMMATICALLY luggy, how can it be possible? Tested on Galaxy tab 2 7 inch, Sony Xperia z1,Galaxy s3, Nexus 5, Galaxy Tab 3 10inch

Comment: Use Traceview and determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: and at the very least, you can post some code.  Otherwise we can't really say why.